# Attach for Update Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I am trying to do an update for a table using EF 5.x using attach. this table has other fields that are required but its an existing row. so i am trying to update without any fetch. userid is the primary key for the table. i am trying to update the status. but it throws an EntityValidationErrors saying password is required which is another required field but not primary key. since this is a update to existing row why do you need to provide the requried fields for update?

```
    var webUser = new WebUser() { UserId = webUserId, OnlineStatus = (sbyte)status };
    using (var dbxupdate = new xEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            dbxupdate.WebUsers.Attach(webUser);
dbxupdate.Entry(webUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
            dbxupdate.Entry(webUser).Property(x => x.OnlineStatus).IsModified = true;
            dbxupdate.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: on the first line you're creating a new `webUser` and not fetching one from the database. try setting a breakpoint and see if the `webUser's` password isn't `null`.

Comment: i didn;t want to fetch the data. since i was going to do an update and i already have a primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In entity framework, You can't update a field without setting appropriate values for other fields. so it is better to use a stored procedure for your job. And the other way is to fetch the record and then update the field.

Comment: You can set dbxupdate.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false to disable validation on save as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33121240/2353894

Comment: The dirty and the best solution. You might be faced a LOT of issues when trying to update an existing tables using EF.

Answer (score 16):

`.Attach()` is really only useful for updating entities in a detached scenario like this:

```
User entity = null;

using (var db = new DbContext()) {
    entity = (from p in db.Users
              where p.Id == 1
              select p).FirstOrDefault();

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(entity.Name); //Outputs "Jane Doe"
}

entity.Name = "John Doe" //Modified while no longer connected to database

using (var db = new DbContext()) {
    db.Users.Attach(entity);
    db.Entry(entity).Property(a => a.Name).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(entity.Name); //Now outputs "John Doe"
}
```

In your scenario, the entity you're creating isn't being retrieved by its key and the database is treating it as an entirely new entity. I assume that your password is a non-nullable field which then causes EF to throw an error when it attempts to save your changes. If you didn't have any such errors then EF would automatically null out any fields that you didn't modify and then save the entity (which isn't the result you're looking for either).

In order to make the changes that you really want, try something like the following:

```
using (var db = new DbContext()) {
    db.Users
        .Single(a => (a.Id == 1))
        .OnlineStatus = ((sbyte)status);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And then add whatever other error handling/validation code that you want. Alternatively you could store the entity in variable for making changes to more than one field at a time. EF should automatically determine which values have been altered and only generate the SQL required to make those changes. Meaning that if you have something like:

```
using (var db = new DbContext()) {
    foreach (var item in entityList) {
        var entity = db.Users.Single(a => (a.Id == item.Id));

        entity.Name = item.Name;
        entity.Address = item.Address;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

then EF should only update the entities/fields that are actually affected by this code. If the Name or Address stays the same then EF will skip that field for that entity when it saves the changes to the database.

Comment: IQueryable.Single performs a fetch so this doesn't totally answer the question.

Comment: @carlin.scott I think there was a misunderstanding and have adjusted the last code block to address your comment; please let know if this was insufficient. The deferred execution feature means that Entity Framework won't bother fetching until the call to `SaveChanges` is made; at which point an update statement will be generated per entity. Something like `update a set a.[Name] = @0, a.[Address] = @1 from [someTable] as a where a.[Id] = @2;`.

Comment: LINQ defers execution of the query until it returns a concrete type. The Single() method returns a concrete type. Have you checked that the query generated by this matches your expectations?

Answer (score 2):

The entity is validated on save, regardless of whether it was attached or loaded from the database. If you use validation attributes or a validation method, the entity must pass validation to be saved.

If you have a `[Required]` attribute on the password field I think you are quite stuck. You probably have to load the entity and then update the info instead of just attaching it.

Comment: no i do not have that Data attribute. its required on Db level but not on EF , i guess ADO.net pulled that attribute from db. i do not see that attribute on generated code

Comment: it looks like i have to create a SP to do this.

Comment: If you want to update only part of the record without first loading the entire entity an SP is probably a good way yes.

Answer (score 0):

try this: replace the first line with (place this inside the `using` statement)
`var wu = dbxupdate.webUsers.single(i=>i.id== webUserId);

 wu.OnlineStatus = whatever;`
code continues...  in order to update an entity you must get an instance of it. otherwise you're creating a new one where properties that are not declared get a `null` value.