# Updating an entity with required properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I realise that updating entities without first selecting them is a common problem and many solutions are already on StackOverflow, however after reading these I'm still having a problem.

I'm using the following code to update a User entitiy:

```
  using (var context = GetContext())
  {
    var userEntity = new UserEntity() { ID = userUpdate.ID };
    context.Users.Attach(userEntity);
    context.Entry(userEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(userUpdate);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

However this results in a `DbEntityValidationException` being thrown because my User entitiy has some required properties but these aren't necessarily set on the updated entity.

Is there any way around this or is it simply a case of removing the required properties?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you limit the available constructors for `UserEntity` to ones that don't initialise it in an invalid state?

Comment: I don't have values for the required properties in this instance - a User entity requires the Email property for example, but perhaps only the user's name is being updated and so the userUpdate contains nothing else. Without selecting the user from the database, I can't know what those required properties are set to.

Selecting the entity then updating it _does_ work, but it's not exactly ideal to make an unnecessary query if I don't have to.

Comment: @NathanCooper There needs to be a parameterless constructor or EF won't be able to create any entities.

Comment: @DavidG I believe you can make it protected

Comment: you can use `context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`. But one point with your method is that every property of the entity is re-set if userUpdate is of the type of the entity. So every property may be marked as changed if their initialisation values differ between userEntity and userUpdate.

Comment: Just found this setting and posted an answer only a couple of minutes before seeing your comment, but thanks! This seems to be the best solution. The userUpdate object is an instance of a separate data transfer class which maps more or less 1:1 with the entity, bar a few values which shouldn't leave the database methods such as hashes, salts etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found an answer here: [Entity Framework/MVC3: temporarily disable validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099949)

By temporarily disabling validation I can bypass the checks and insert any number of values without retrieving the required properties first:

```
using (var context = GetContext())
{
  var userEntity = new UserEntity() { ID = userUpdate.ID };
  context.Users.Attach(userEntity);
  context.Entry(userEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(userUpdate);

  // Disable entity validation
  context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to update particular fields in your entity without having to retrieve the entire thing from the database first:

```
var userEntity = new UserEntity() { ID = userUpdate.ID };
userEntity.SomeProperty = userUpdate.SomeProperty;

//Tell EF to only update the SomeProperty value:
context.Entry(userEntity).Property(x => x.SomeProperty).IsModified = true;

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help with the issue of the required properties not being set. An exception is still thrown unless I remove the required properties from the configuration.