# Is it possible to improve EF6 WarmUp time?

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have an application in which I verify the following behavior: the first requests after a long period of inactivity take a long time, and timeout sometimes.
Is it possible to control how the entity framework manages dispose of the objects? Is it possible mark some Entities to never be disposed?
...in order to avoid/improve the warmup time?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons that similar queries will have an improved response time are manifold.

- Most Database Management Systems cache parts of the fetched data, so that similar queries in the near future will be faster. If you do query `Teachers with their Students`, then the `Teachers` table will be joined with the `Students` table. This join result is quite often cached for a while. The next query for `Teachers with their Students` will reuse this join result and thus become faster
- `DbContext` caches queried object. If you select a `Single` teacher, or `Find` one, it is kept in local memory. This is to be able to detect which items are changed when you call `SaveChanges`. If you `Find` the same `Teacher` again, this query will be faster. I'm not sure if the same happens if you query 1000 `Teachers`.
- When you create a `DbContext` object, the initializer is checked to see if the model has been changed or not.

So it might seem wise not to `Dispose()` a created `DbContext`, yet you see that most people keep the `DbContext` alive for a fairly short time:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    var fetchedTeacher = dbContext.Teachers
        .Where(teacher => teacher.Id = ...)
        .Select(teacher => new
        {
            Id = teacher.Id,
            Name = teacher.Name,
            Students = teacher.Students.ToList(),
         })
         .FirstOrDefault();
    return fetchedTeacher;
}
// DbContext is Disposed()
```

At first glance it would seem that it would be better to keep the `DbContext` alive. If someone asks for the same `Teacher`, the `DbContext` wouldn't have to ask the database for it, it could return the local Teacher..

However, keeping a `DbContext` alive might cause that you get the wrong data. If someone else changes the `Teacher` between your first and second query for this `Teacher`, you would get the old `Teacher` data.

Hence it is wise to keep the life time of a `DbContext` as short as possible.

**Is there nothing I can do to improve the speed of the first query?**

Yes you can!

One of the first things you could do is to set the initialize of your database such that it doesn't check the existence and model of the database. Of course you can only do this when you are fairly sure that your database exists and hasn't changed.

```
// constructor; disables initializer
public SchoolDBContext() : base(...)
{            
    //Disable initializer
    Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(null);
}
```

Another thing could be, if you already have fetched your object to update the database, and you are sure that no one else changed the object, you can `Attach` it, instead of fetching it again, [as is shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105702/attach-for-update-entity-framework)

Normal usage:

```
// update the name of the teacher with teacherId
void ChangeTeacherName(int teacherId, string name)
{
    using (var dbContext = new SchoolContext(...))
    {
        // fetch the teacher, change the name and save
        Teacher fetchedTeacher = dbContext.Teachers.Find(teacherId);
        fetchedTeader.Name = name;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Using `Attach` to update an earlier fetched Teacher:

```
void ChangeTeacherName (Teacher teacher, string name)
{
    using (var dbContext = new SchoolContext(...))
    {
          dbContext.Teachers.Attach(teacher);
          dbContext.Entry(teacher).Property(t => t.Name).IsModified = true;
          dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Using this method doesn't require to fetch the Teacher again. During SaveChanges the value of `IsModified` of all properties of all `Attached` items is checked. If needed they will be updated.